# How to get average of some table values that are from the same attribute

Tags: mysql, sql, database

So I have this table, three of the columns are:

[image]

So I wanna get the `id_keg`, and the `persen` (SELECT DISTINCT).
The `persen` is the average of `persen` with the same `id_keg`.

The result will be pretty much like this:

```
----------------------
|  id_keg  |  persen |
----------------------
|   202    |  98.00  |
|   101    |  98.89  |
|   102    |  96.43  |
----------------------
```

I can't seem to find the way to do this. I want to get id_keg and the persen.
I only understand this and I know this won't do:

```
SELECT AVG (persen) WHERE id_keg=202 FROM laporan.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a Group By clause:

```
SELECT id_keg, AVG(persen) FROM laporan GROUP BY id_keg
```

Answer (score 2):

You need `group by` while using the aggregate function `avg`

```
select 
id_keg, avg(persen) as persen
from laporan group by id_keg
```